# Custom emoji keyboard with custom images in android

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard, emoji

Hello i make a keyboard with custom images for emoji. when i press the emoji then it gives me a Chinese output. please solve my issue.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TntX.jpg)

please help me..

Comment: Can you add some code to the question please

Comment: thanks for your response, sir i just replace the images of emoji from [this](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard) tutorial

Comment: Hi Dani, where you able to resolve this issue

Comment: No issue didnot resolve.